# str_replace for UTF-16 characters

Tags: php, string, unicode

I have some strings containing characters such as `\x{1f601}` which I want to replace with some text.

When I do this using preg_replace, it would be something like:

```
preg_replace('/\x{1f601}/u', '######', $str)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with str_replace:

```
str_replace("\x{1f601}", '######', $str)
```

How can I make such replacements work with str_replace?

Comment: Your text literally contains the 9-character long string "\x{1f601}", or it contains the character ""? And how does UTF-16 play into this?

Comment: Are you saying that `preg_replace` works, but `str_replace` doesn't? Also *UTF-16* is a way to encode Unicode characters. Do you have PHP running in UTF-8 mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace` is a  Regex parser/replacer, which is a Perl Regular expression engine, but `str_replace` is *NOT* and replaces things with a plaintext method

The Preg_replace you have got can be seen here in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kF9xJ9/1), stating that:

> matches the character  with position 0x1f601 (128513 decimal or 373001 octal) in the character set

But this could be transferable to a non-regex find and replace,by copy and pasting that face smiley symbol into the str_replace directly.

```
$str = str_replace("", '######', $str)
```

Or, by reading [deceze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993149/str-replace-for-utf-16-characters/37993894?noredirect=1#comment63431933_37993894) which gives you a clean, small solution.

**Additional:**

You are using a character set that is non-standard so it may be useful for you to explore [Mb_Str_replace](https://gist.github.com/sgmurphy/3098836) (gitHub) which is an accompanyment (but not directly from) the [mb_string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) collection of PHP functions.

**Finally:**

Why do you need to do string replace whe you are already doing regex preg_replace? Also please read the manual which states all of this fairly clearly.

Comment: You *could* write `"\xF0\x9F\x98\x81"` as string literal equivalent without needing to copy and paste  and worrying about your source code encoding...

Comment: Note that the above is the string literal for the *UTF-8 encoded* character . If the string OP is working on is in fact not UTF-8 encoded, they'll need to adapt that to whatever encodings they need...

Comment: And you can use "Example #2 Examining the individual bytes of a UTF-8 string" from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php to figure out the string literal equivalent if you're trying to use deceze's approach.